# How can I use OLEDB to populate listview from a .XLS file

Tags: c#, oledb

Hi I have a small problem. I am coding a program that displays the columns of an Excel file file and next to it the columns of an Access database in two seperate listviews. You select the sheet and table to display with a combo box. The Access columns display fine but the columns of the Excel sheet won't display no matter what I do but the sheets appear in the combo box without any problems but the columns won't appear no matter what I do. Is there any specific way that I can do this that works because I couldn't find anything on the Internet.

This is the part that is supposed to insert it
    {

```
             {

            // lvwDestination.Columns.Add(_dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);

            lvwSource.Columns.Add("Fields in Database", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

            for (int i = 0; i < _Sourcedt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                ListViewItem lvwItem = new ListViewItem("" + _Sourcedt.Columns[i].ColumnName, 0);
                lvwSource.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { lvwItem });

            }


        }

    }
```

Another part also that I may have messed up it worked for access but not for excel. I also modified the Select statement little

private void cboSourceName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // create the adapter and fill the DataSet

```
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter =
           new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from " + cboSourceName.Text +"" + "", _SourceConn);
        lvwSource.Columns.Clear();

        lvwSource.Items.Clear();

        _Sourcedt.Columns.Clear();//Contains all the columns in selected table

        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(_Sourcedt);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        LoadColumns2();

    }
```

And also the connect part

private void btnConnectSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

```
            string connString =



            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + txtSourcePath.Text + ";" +
            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
            //"Password=" + txtPWSource + ";";

            _SourceConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
           // _OleConn[1].ConnectionString = connString;
            _SourceConn.Open();

            _Sourcedt = new DataTable();

            LoadCombo2();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
```

Comment: Ok well I'm quite new to coding so which part do you need

Comment: I was looking for the code that read in your excel file as well.  If your ListView is empty it is probably because _Sourcedt.Rows.Count = 0, you need to work out why you are not getting any rows e.g. you are reading in an empty sheet from excel. Use the `Add` method rather than the `AddRange`, Add is for adding a single item AddRange for adding multiple items.

Comment: i checked that already the sheet is not empty

Comment: `lvwSource.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(_Sourcedt.Columns[i].ColumnName, 0));` should work.  Notice i have removed the empty string from the beginning of the constructor.  This is an old trick used in JavaScript and other weakly typed languages to force the result to a string.  c# is strongly typed so this is not needed.

Comment: hmmm not working it definitely must be the read part

Comment: I posted the other parts hope you can make sense of it

Comment: Nevermind I dropped trying to get the data in a listview because a Datagrid view works much better but thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listview is not a great idea to use in this case. The best way to do it is to populate your data from Excel into a Datagrid